# Multi-column, multi-row pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to pass the row with index 0 to a multi-column df. That is, I want to have the same df but with index-0 row in bold, above the vertical line. I have tried to do this without success. Help would be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjNi2.png)

Comment: If your data provide from a csv or an excel file, you should use `header=[0, 1]` as parameter of `pd.read_csv` or `pd.read_excel` function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you could try this to transfer your first row from the original df to the head of the new one.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=
                  {'Name': ["Peter", "Andy", "Bob", "Lisa"],
                   'Age': [50, 40, 34, 39],
                   'Nationality': ["USA", "Australian", "Candian", "Mexican"]}
                  )

dict = {}
for titel in df.iloc[0]:
    dict[titel] = ["TestValue", "Testvalue"]
    
print(dict)
dfN = pd.DataFrame(data=dict) # new Dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas dataframe can have multiple column headers for columns or rows.

Make a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.randint(
        0, 10, (6,4)),
    columns=["a", "b", "c", "d"])
```

Insert a second column index.

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    zip(['A', 'B','C', 'D'], 
        df.columns))
```

output

```
   A  B  C  D
   a  b  c  d
0  4  9  5  1
1  7  5  3  7
2  1  1  5  1
3  8  3  8  3
4  3  8  8  2
5  5  2  3  5
```